# Would like to specify local file path for WSDL to generate REST APIs from it using Publisher

Tags: rest, soap, wsdl, wso2-api-manager

I have a WSDL with relative paths for the ".xsd" schema files on my local machine.  I am trying to generate REST APIs from this WSDL using Publisher.  I am using the "file://" URL pattern to specify the path but am having challenges.  I have folder names with spaces between them (e.g., "My WSDL Folder"). I would appreciate it if I could be shown an example as to how to go about specifying this. Thanks!

Note:  I am using WSO2-AM 2.6.0 and have updated it using WUM as late as midnight of Oct 7, 2019.

Comment: Could you post a code sample of what you are trying to do here, even if it is not working? This will help everyone answer your question better.

Comment: Thanks @Christine.  I don't have any code for this as it is just a simple generation of REST APIs from a WSDL on the local file system.  I don't have the SOAP service corresponding to the WSDL running anywhere but am thinking that it is not required to have the service running to just generate the API definition from the WSDL.  I can even use the sample WSDL at this site to test this out:  https://www.w3.org/2001/04/wsws-proceedings/uche/wsdl.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the URL in the format file:///{path-to-wsdl-file}/{wsdl-name}.wsdl. When there are spaces in the folder name, URL encode it and add.